# Very fast boolean difference between two meshes

Tags: algorithm, 3d

Let's say I have a static object and a movable object which can be moved and rotated, what is the best way to very quickly calculate the difference of those two meshes?

Precision here is not so important, speed is though, since I have to use it in the update phase of the main loop.

Maybe, given the strict time limit, modifying the static object's vertices and triangles directly is to be preferred. Should voxels be preferred here instead?

EDIT: The use case is an interactive viewer of a wood panel (parallelepiped) and a milling tool (a revolved contour, some like [these](http://www.technologystudent.com/equip1/vert2a.png)).
The milling tool can be rotated and can work oriented at varying degrees (5 axes).

EDIT 2: The milling tool may not pierce the wood.

EDIT 3: The panel can be as large as 6000x2000mm and the milling tool can be as little as 3x3mm.

Comment: What "time limit" are you referring to?

Comment: Something like 1/60 of a second (60 fps) or even 1/30s...

Comment: I've updated my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Do you have any picture of a real object done with this technique? Every idea I come up with won't work in some situations so I need some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the best possible performance then the generic CSG approach may be too slow for you (but still depending on meshes and target hardware).

You may try to find some specialized algorithm, coded for your specific meshes. Let's say you have two cubes - one is a 'wall' and second is a 'window' - then it's much easier/faster to compute resulting mesh with your custom code, than full CSG. Unfortunately you don't say anything about your meshes.

You may also try to make it a 2D problem, use some simplified meshes to compute the result that will 'look like expected'.

If the movement of your meshes is somehow limited you may be able to precompute full or partial results for different mesh combinations to use at runtime.

You may use some space partitioning like BSP or Octrees to divide your meshes during precomputing stage. This way you could split one big problem into many smaller ones that may be faster to compute or at least to make the solution multi-threaded.

You've said about voxels - if you're fine with their look and limits you may voxelize both meshes and just read and mix two voxel values, instead of one. Then you would triangulate it using algorithm like Marching Cubes.

Those are all just some general ideas but we'll need better info to help you more.

**EDIT:**

With your description it looks like you're modeling some bas-relief, so you may use [Relief Mapping](https://www.google.pl/search?q=relief%20mapping&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji4d3bkMzRAhXDYJoKHUonA-YQ_AUICCgB&biw=1446&bih=849) to fake this effect. It's based on a `height map` stored as a texture, so you'd need to just update few pixels of the texture and render a plane. It should be quite fast compared to other approaches, the downside is that it's based on height map, so you can't get shapes that Tee Slot or Dovetail cutter would create.

If you want the real geometry then I'd start from a simple plane as your panel (don't need full 3D yet, just a front surface) and divide it with a 2D grid. The grid element should be slightly bigger than the drill size and every element is a separate mesh. In the frame update you'd cut one, or at most 4 elements that are touched with a drill. Thanks to this grid all your cutting operations will be run with very simple mesh so they may work with your intended speed. You can also cut all current elements in separate threads. After the cutting is done you'll upload to the GPU only currently modified elements so you may end up with quite complex mesh but small modifications per frame.

Comment: I've updated my question. Now my use case should be clearer

Comment: Sadly, I can't use a flat 2D panel to start because the milling tool is mounted on a 5 axes machine so it could also start from the sides...
Subdiving the panel into small parallelepipeds could work, but since the panel could be as large as 6000x2000mm and the milling tool as little as 3x3mm, maybe voxels are the best option after all...  
PS: I have edited the question with those details.